# How to get data binding to work with RRO or SRRO

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-databinding, rro

So android let you use databinding to bind observable data directly to the XML which works and I am very familiar with.

Now the question is how would this work with Runtime Resource Overlay?

RRO allows you to have multiple different resources for different scenarios. This is different from a cradle build flavour. And different from using qualifiers for resources.

Since RRO is pretty much replaces only your resources how would you do databinding with that? Since you can't have code in RRO?